# Is there a geometry meaning of the commutator of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Conjugation has a geometric meaning: $aba^{-1}$ is the transform $b$ under coordination change $a$. For example in the symmetry of tetrahedron, let $a$ be the anti-clockwise $1/3$ round rotation around the altitude through vertex $A$, $b$ be the reflection by the plane through edge $AB$, the $aba^{-1}$ is the reflection of the plane through edge $AC$, which is just $b$ after relabeling vertices $A$ $B$$C$ $D$ by $a$.

> Is there a similar geometric meaning of the commutator, $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you consider this geometric, but: If $a b a^{-1} b^{-1} = e$, rearranging gives $ab = ba$, and vice versa. So, the commutator of two symmetries is a directed measure of the failure of those symmetries to commute. On a Lie group, passing to the infinitesimal level gives rise to the notion of Lie bracket of left-invariant vector fields, or just as well, the Lie algebra commutator. If you consider this geometric, I'm happy to write this up as a short answer.

Comment: Right, which is why the quantity $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in [G, G]$ (where $G$ is the group of symmetries) is a measure of how $a, b$ fail to commute.

Comment: @Travis so commutant ( or commutator subgroup) , as a group at total, has a meaning : measure of noncommutability of the original group; however, for a single commutator, is there a meaning?

Comment: Yes, $a b a^{-1} b^{-1}$ measures whether those the two elements $a, b$ commute with one another. If they fail to commute, it also measures, roughly speaking, in "what direction" they fail to commute. An instructive example is to taking $a, b \in SO(3, \Bbb R)$ to be small anticlockwise turns around two different axes. Then, to second order, their commutator is a small turn around the third axis---whether the turn is anticlockwise or clockwise depends on whether the positive directions of the axes form a right- or left-handed orientation of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @Travis this is something interesting which I never thought of, would you kindly put it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I'll write an answer up now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is arguably an algebraic fact more than a geometric one, but for any group $G$ and $a, b \in G$ rearranging gives that $$a b a^{-1} b^{-1} = 1_G \qquad \textrm{iff} \qquad a b = b a ,$$ so the commutator $a b a^{-1} b^{-1} \in [G, G]$ of $a, b$ is a measure of the failure of those two elements (or geometrically, symmetries) to commute and, if the elements don't commute, roughly speaking a "direction" of that failure.

An instructive example is the following: Consider the group $SO(3)$ of oriented rotations of $\Bbb R^3$. Small anticlockwise rotation about the $x$- and $y$-axes are respectively given to first order by
$$\pmatrix{1\\&1&-\epsilon\\&\epsilon&1} ,
  \pmatrix{1&&\epsilon\\&1&\\-\epsilon&&1} ,$$
and forming their commutator gives to second order that
$$\pmatrix{1&\epsilon^2\\-\epsilon^2&1\\&&1} ,$$
which is a small clockwise rotation about the $z$-axis. (Instead forming the commutator in the reverse order gives a small anticlockwise rotation about the $z$-axis instead.)

For Lie groups of positive dimension like $SO(3, \Bbb R)$, a convenient algebraic way to formalize the idea of working with "small" symmetries (in our example, symmetries that don't rotate the sphere too much) is to pass to the level of infinitesimal symmetries. We can identify these symmetries with the tangent space $T_{1_G} G$ of $G$ at the identity $1_G$. In the case of $SO(3, \Bbb R)$, we can identify $T_I SO(3, \Bbb R)$ with the space of $3 \times 3$ antisymmetric real matrices, and linearization of the group multiplication law (more precisely, of the conjugation map) gives a *Lie bracket* on $T_I SO(3, \Bbb R)$, a natural, bilinear, antisymmetric map that in this case coincides with the usual commutator $$(A, B) \mapsto [A, B] := AB - BA$$ of matrices. The vector space $T_I SO(3, \Bbb R)$ together with the Lie bracket operation defines the *Lie algebra* $\mathfrak{so}(3, \Bbb R)$ of $SO(3, \Bbb R)$.

Comment: This is essentially the same formula, except that I've truncated the expressions at second order in $\theta = -\epsilon$ to make the computation easier and the answer more transparent. From the usual Taylor series we know that $\cos \theta = 1 + O(\epsilon^2)$ and $\sin \theta = -\epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)$. Anyway, you're welcome---I hope you found the answer useful!

Comment: I mean seems there is a typo: rotation about y-axis is not $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & & -\epsilon \\ & 1 & \\ \epsilon & & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ but   $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & & \epsilon \\ & 1 & \\ -\epsilon & & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: May I rephrase it as: $r_x r_y r_x^{-1} r_y^{-1} - e \approx r_x r_y - r_y r_x$, so the deviation of commutator from $e$ shows how different is $r_x r_y$ to $r_y r_x$?

Comment: @athosd To formalize your idea, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula